# How to populate second drop down box on first drop down (Hard)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to populate my second drop down box based on what value the user has chosen on the first. This is what I have done so far:

In the PHP file:

```
function displayDropDown()
{
    $table_tester = "TBL_TESTER_LIST";
    $query_string = "select * from $table_tester";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<select id=\"tester_type\" onChange=\"getTesterType();\">";
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tester_type = $data['tester_type'];
        echo "<option value='$tester_type'>$tester_type</option>"; // first drop down
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

function displaySecondDropDown($selected_tester_type)
{
    $table_tester = "TBL_TESTER_LIST";
    $query_string = "select * from $table_tester where tester_type = '$selected_tester_type'";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<select>";
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tester_name = $data['tester_name'];
        echo "<option value='$tester_name'>$tester_name</option>";// second drop down
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

?>
<?php

$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

if($action=="insert")
{
    $tester_type = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_type']);
    $tester_name  = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_name']);

    echo checkDuplicateTesterName($tester_type, $tester_name);
}
else if($action=="displayDropDown")
{
    $selected_tester_type = $_REQUEST['tester_type'];

    echo displayDropDown();
    echo displaySecondDropDown($selected_tester_type);
}

?>
```

In the external JavaScript file:

```
function displayDropDown()
{
    var page = "database.php";

    $.post(page, {
        action : "displayDropDown"
    }, function(data) {
        $("div#drop_two_list").html(data);
    });
}

function getTesterType()
{
    var tester_type = $("#tester_type").val();
    var page = "database.php";

    $.post(page, {
        tester_type : tester_type
        }, function(data) {
        $("div#drop_two_list").html(data);
    });
}
```

In the HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete Tester</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">displayDropDown();</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Delete Tester</h3>
        <div id="drop_two_list"></div>
        <table class="deleteTable">
            <tr>
                <td/><td><br>
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.close();"/>
                    <input type="button" name="send" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTester();"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Two drop down boxes do appear. The first one has values(which are wrong I'll explain in the later part) and the second is empty. Also, an error appeared: `Notice: Undefined index: tester_type in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Signup/module1/database.php on line 86` which is `$selected_tester_type = $_REQUEST['tester_type'];` in the PHP file. If I were to select a value in the first one then another error would replace everything on the page with: `Notice: Undefined index: action in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Signup/module1/database.php on line 75` which is `$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);`.

Now onto the part where I state why the first drop down box has the *wrong* values. Before proceeding, to understand my question better here is the table(TBL_TESTER_LIST) that I am trying to populate the drop down boxes with.
Note: I am only showing 5 sample rows in random order because I have more than **500 rows** in this table and wouldn't want to put everything here.

```
 id      tester_type   tester_name
 1         LMX           LMX-01
 2         LMX           LMX-04
 26        LCX           LCX-06
 40        CAT           CAT-14
 95        HPPS          HPPS-01
```

The tester_type column is what I want to populate my first drop down box with, and tester_name column is what I want to populate my second drop down box with, accordingly. As you can see, there duplicates for tester_type because one tester_name can belong to the same tester_type(An example would be green apple no.1(tester_name) is an apple(tester_type) and green apple no.2(tester_name) is also an apple(tester_type)).

What I am currently getting in my first drop down box is just: LMX, LMX, LMX, LMX, and so on. That is because my first 31 Rows are LMX. How do I code my drop first down box such that it would only display one of each type, and my second drop down box would display the values that are based on what the user selected?

An example would be: If the user selects LMX in the first drop down box, then all the tester_names that are LMX tester_type would populate the second drop down box.

If more information needed on the table, please do tell me. Been searching for a solution for 5 days and I don't seem to be close to a conclusion.

Comment: In both JS functions you need to pass `action` and `tester_type`.
For `displayDropDown` function, `action` will have value "displayDropDown" and `tester_type` will be "".
In second Function. Put `action` also with value "displayDropDown".
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm that might be one of the errors, however I'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without asking why your table is structured that way, would it not be enough to use the DISTINCT clause in your query to eliminate duplicates.

```
select DISTINCT tester_type from $table_tester
```